# Which sites get listed on footer?

Tags: support, footer

I want to know is there any criteria through which sites get listed in footer? I am asking this because bicycles seems to be a trivial topic to be listed.

Comment: Popularity perhaps? Which SE sites aren't listed in the footer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Well for me parenting or physical fitness or history deserve a better chance. Also, it is tough to find the link of the other sites, because the stackexchange.com/sites seems just like Million dollar homepage.

Comment: Well I don't know what "million dollar homepage" means but bicycles seems to have more active users than physical history or fitness. Obviously there is only so much room in the footer, and they have to draw the line somewhere. If history and physical fitness have less users than bicycles, why do they deserve "a better chance"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's actually The Million Dollar Homepage, proper noun. It has its own [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million_Dollar_Homepage).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the sites that were either part of the original trilogy (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User) and those that have graduated the Area 51/Beta process are listed in each other's footer.  Careers in also included in this bunch.  Bicycles went through the phases of the Area 51 system and graduated [11 months ago](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles).

All of the sites currently in Beta are listed in the footer of all of the other Beta sites.

Area 51 itself is listed in both the footers for the Beta sites and the established ones.

Comment: @dystroy If it adds something, there's no need to delete it.  I'm not completely sure of the sort order, it looks to be when the sites graduated.

Comment: Pleased to see that there is a process attached to it and not some random picking up and listing.