# Order of others StackExchange links in the footer

Tags: support, footer

I never really understood the order chosen to display the list of other Stack Exchange site (`SO`, `api/apps`, `careers`, `serverfault.com`, and so on.) in the footer of the page.

Is the order related to the activity on these sites? Their "ages" (since they leaved the beta stage)?

Why the alphabetical order is not used? This way, it should be easier to find a specific site, especially when one wants to access a SE site he is not used to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is answered only [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138546/which-sites-get-listed-on-footer#comment389926_138549) on other question:

> It's not sorted by popularity. It's sorted by [the order in which they graduated to full site status](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).

I confirmed this to be true, the first site that was launched via area 51 is [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) so all the sites before are part of the "core" and the trilogy sites.

Screenshot to clarify and in case something will change:

> [image]

Comment: This answers how they are ordered, but why? With such a large number of sites, listing them in anything but alphabetical order makes the footer useless at best.

Comment: @user113215 why useless? For some people, knowing which are the newer sites is helpful information. Guess that was the initial order and it just stuck as the network grew. If one wants to sift through the list ordered by name, it's possible [here in this list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name).